# Windows Defender identifies .exe of default Visual Studio 2019 Windows Desktop Application template as malicious

Tags: visual-studio-2019, win32gui, antivirus

I am working on a simple Windows GUI that does some file parsing on the files that our main products generate to aid the user in processing the data that we collect for them. We want it to be a simple, standalone executable that they will not have to install in order to use.

Throughout development, we did not think of the effects that antivirus might have on our executable. Recently, Windows has been instantly quarantining our executable. After submitting our executable to VirusTotal, we get flagged by 10-12 different antivirus services (including Windows Defender).

In an attempt to narrow down a rogue, malicious library that I may be using, I have stripped the application down to the bare bones with no improvements. I then thought I should just create a blank Windows application in Visual Studio and submit that executable to VirusTotal. The results were horrendous and can be viewed here (notice how Windows Defender was one of the services that flagged it): https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/18dc4e24caa370f62b08e78f00082fbe2deb4d9ae97e9fa7cbf2772f29c9964e/detection

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there something I may not have configured correctly in the Visual Studio project settings?

I appreciate any feedback on this.

Comment: You probably need to configure Defender. When Windows 10 started to delete all my recent and historic executables I took the brutal route. I formatted the drive and re-installed  Windows 7, followed by an AV program that prompted me and was easy to configure folder exceptions to its regime.

Comment: Antivirus generally looks for code snippets that match a known virus signature. Assuming you _aren't_ linking to something bad, some pre-initialized [binary] data array may have a sequence that matches. I googled: `windows defender false positive` and one of the links was: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/all/windows-defender-false-positives/f320ca32-bdd6-4dd3-9d82-14b5b22fc1fc

Comment: From the VirusTotal page, a number of engines identify your program as some variant of `Gen:Variant.Midie.71049`, which seems to be a malware "installer" virus. You mentioned that you _don't_ want a user to have to install your program. If you did create an installable version (with `.ini` et. al.) and created a install package, does that work?

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for the feedback, but that would be unreasonable to ask of our customers. But I will look into certain Windows Defender settings to see if there is anything being a little bit too harsh

Comment: @CraigEstey Thank you for getting back to me, I am looking through the link that you posted and your idea about creating an installable version is interesting. I will continue to look into that.

Comment: Yes not very helpful sorry. I do use a few imported applications that were not "installed" such as the text editor Notepad++ but IIRC that was not squashed by Defender. Perhaps there is a list of known safe software, or perhaps it is "signed".

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes I think so, a couple days ago I submitted a false positive report to Microsoft and just saw a couple minutes ago that they got back to my support ticket. It does seem that Windows Defender doesn't squash it on my local machine but still gets flagged by VirusTotal. Starting to think that maybe VirusTotal has old definitions or shouldn't be trusted as the end-all solution for testing antivirus compatibility.